# How to pass the argument into printf in awk?

Tags: awk, arguments

format.awk is simple.

```
#! /usr/bin/awk
{
    printf("%52s\\\n" ,$0);
}
```

The command is going to execute.

```
awk -f format.awk   test
```

Now i want to make the number 52 in **printf("%52s\\n" ,$0);** as a varible.

```
awk -f format.awk -v n=52
```

If i want to pass argument 52 into  format.awk,how to write the statement

```
printf("%ns\\\n" ,$0);
awk -f format.awk  -v n=52 test
```

awk: run time error: improper conversion(number 1) in printf("%-ns\
")
FILENAME="test" FNR=2 NR=2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, see the examples below:

```
kent$  awk 'BEGIN{a=3;printf "%.*f\n",a,10/3}'           
3.333  
           
kent$  awk 'BEGIN{a=7;printf "%.*f\n",a,10/3}'    
3.3333333
```

The syntax is same as `printf()` of C, with `*`

---

#### Edit (add doc quote)

> The C library printf’s dynamic width and prec capability (e.g.,
> "%*.*s") is supported. Instead of supplying explicit width and/or prec
> values in the format string, they are passed in the argument list.

Quote from gnu awk manual:
https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Format-Modifiers.html

Answer (score 0):

In `awk`, string interpolation does not work like that. You need to say

```
printf("%" n "s", $0)
```